# How to update multiple values for specific ID numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website and I want to update some empty values for some IDs.

In phpMyAdmin, editing a single row gives me this result:

```
UPDATE  `sample_dir`.`page` SET  `votes` =  '4', `rating` =  '7.00'
WHERE  `page`.`id` =12676170;
```

However, if I try to update multiple rows at once (I was thinking putting a comma between the IDs will do it but it doesn't). I used this sql command:

```
UPDATE  "sample_dir`.`page` SET  `votes` =  '1', `rating` =  '9.00'
WHERE  `page`.`id` =2042085451,12676170,733543897;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Use `in` -- `id in (1,2,3)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IN()` operator

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

```
UPDATE  `sample_dir`.`page` SET  `votes` =  '1', `rating` =  '9.00'
WHERE  `page`.`id` IN (2042085451,12676170,733543897);
```